# STL practice problems

Tags: c++, stl

I have recently gone through the concepts of STL in C++. I want to improve my skills of using STL. I request if someone can direct me to a book or link where I can find sufficient problems where I can learn how to apply STL. If there are solutions with little analysis it would be of even more help. 
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Well for starters, [it's not called the STL](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/).

Answer (score 2):

An excellent online resource is [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/). You will occasionally hear about [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/) but that is not reliable and notoriously wrong so I would advise against it.

Comment: It's less wrong these days... and both are not too reliable inasmuch as they are not *The Standard*.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Sure, but they have a nice index and are well searchable. Together with the examples provided on the individual pages, they work nicely both to get to know the standard library and to remember some particular member function prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with easy ones' in Topcoder practice rooms. Most of them could be solved using STL.